# Is gear worth more glimmer after being upgraded?

Tags: destiny

Given two identical pieces of gear (armour, weapons) with the same level requirement and base stats, is one that has gained "experience" or upgraded worth more glimmer/scrap when you dismantle it? I like to level my extra gear up before selling it but I haven't noticed any clear benefits so far.